# Does std::set<classtype>.find(element) use the == operator from the class to compare the elements?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, stdset

Say I have

```
std::set<classtype> set;
class classtype {
    bool operator==(const classtype& ct) {
        //..
    } 
};
//..
std::set<classtype>::iterator it = set.find(element);
```

Find does use the == operator from the class correct?

Also my reference says it has log(n) worst case runtime where n is the number of elements in the set. How is this realized internally? I understand that the key is that the elements in the set have a order (so insertion takes long to create that order), for integer sets it is clear what order means but for random classes not so much.

Comment: No, it's [`srd::less<Key>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) actually applied as default.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `std`? Also, order is defined by your implementation of a less than operation.

Comment: @scohe001 Of course, a typo.

Comment: how do i do that operator== is used?

Comment: @myelf you cannot sort using `operator==`

Comment: @myelf: If you want to search using your `operator==`, then you can use `std::find`. But then the search is not taking advantage of the ordered nature of the set, and is O(n) instead of O(log n).

Comment: Very hard to do with any speed. == tells you match or not, but not where in the set you are relative to where the target should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the C++ Standard (23.2.4 Associative containers)

> 3 The phrase “equivalence of keys” means the equivalence relation
>   imposed by the comparison and **not the operator== on keys**. That is,
>   two keys k1 and k2 are considered to be equivalent if for the
>   comparison object comp, comp(k1, k2) == false && comp(k2, k1) ==
>   false. For any two keys k1 and k2 in the same container, calling
>   comp(k1, k2) shall always return the same value.

Member function `find` seeks a key according to the comparison object `comp`

If you did not specify explicitly the comparison object then the class uses by default standard functional object `std::less` that uses `operator <` within its operator function. So your class has to have the operator < defined.

If you want to use `operator ==` for comparison values in the set then you can use standard algorithm `std::find` instead of the method `find`.

Comment: can you give a tip what makes sense for a < operator for a std::vector<double>?

Comment: @myelf: You could use the one that is already defined in the standard library, which does a lexicographical comparison. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this does not make much sense for what I am trying to do.

Comment: Oh, thanks! When I use std::set<type>::iterator it= std::find(std::begin(std::set<type>), std::end(std::set<type>), elementOfType) is this what I "want" to do? I guess the runtime of this is bad.

Comment: @myelf  yes. It is a linear search with O( size() ).